# Matplotlib hexbin - get bin borders

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to get the borders of a `matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin` plot?

Say, i have a `pd.DataFrame` with spatial latitude and longitude values, which i plot in a hexbin plot. Afterwards i want to assign the corresponding bin of the hexbin grid to each instance of my `DataFrame`, by checking if the latitude and longitude values of an instance fall in one of the hexbin bins.

Can i assign names or indices to the different bins?

I have already looked in the documentation for the hexbin plot, all i can find are line properties, which describe the lines that are drawn in the plot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'm wishing to do something similar for small hexbins, thinking to:

(1) Get the hexbin centres: 
    hexobj_cen=hexobj.get_offsets()
    lon_hex=hexobj_cen[:,0]       #hexbin lon centre
    lat_hex=hexobj_cen[:,1]      #hexbin lat centre

(2) Run a for loop (for each hexbin centre) to find the Cartesian distance (N.hypot) between that centre from all points put into an array

Then ask if for each hexbin centre, point-hexbin distance is greater than some maximum distance (half the distance between two opposing vertices.

Great if there is a standard way (within pylab.hexbin) to do this, but also couldn't yet find it.